# Проблема версий при создании кастомного апп для SCDF

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

Всем привет!
Локально поднял scdf по гайду - [ссылка](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/)

немного видеоизменил docker-compose:

```
services:
  dataflow-server:
    environment:
      - maven.remote-repositories.repo1.url=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
      - maven.remote-repositories.springRepo.url=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
      - maven.local-repository=/home/cnb/.m2/repository
      - JAVA_VERSION=17
      - BP_JVM_VERSION=-jdk17 
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\user\.m2:/home/cnb/.m2

  skipper-server:
    environment:
      - maven.remote-repositories.repo1.url=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
      - maven.remote-repositories.springRepo.url=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
      - maven.local-repository=/home/cnb/.m2/repository
      - JAVA_VERSION=17
      - BP_JVM_VERSION=-jdk17
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\user\.m2:/home/cnb/.m2
```

дополнительно создал простой кастомный процессор-апп, успешно зарегестрировал его, и беда в том, что когда создаю стрим и деплою его, то все заканчивается статусом - "PARTIAL", в логах пишет:

```
LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

и для меня совсем не понятно почему, апп создан на 17 джаве, и судя по документации scdf все равно каких версий апки, ибо они независимы, тем более в конфиге прописано BP_JVM_VERSION=-jdk17, чтобы апки поднимались на 17 джаве

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась изменением версий докер имеджей:

```
springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:2.9.2 -> springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:2.9.2-SNAPSHOT-jdk17

springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.10.2 -> springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.10.2-jdk17
```